# Angularjs with ngAnimate all images display when only one has the active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have been experimenting with ngAnimate and have created a web-site that has an animation similar to the one for the phonecat tutorial. The web-site is shown [here](http://www.laurie.turpin.talktalk.net). The way it is supposed to work is that there are 5 thumbnails of animals. Below the thumbnails one image should show which is the first image. When any of the other thumbnails are clicked on a new image slides up into place and fades in and the old image slides up and fades out. What is happening though is all the images are showing when the web-site first loads. I can't understand why this is as only one image has the active class and should be the only one showing. However if all the other images are clicked on the web-site works the way it should and only one image shows at a time.

Below is the code.

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Images Project</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="myapp.js"></script>
    <script src= "controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="view-container"
    <div ng-view class="view-frame"></div>
    </body>


</body>
</html>
```

display-images.html

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div ng-repeat="image in images" class="col-sm-4 col-md-2">
                <div href="#" class="thumbnail">
                    <img ng-src="{{ image.image }}"
                        ng-click="setImage(image.image)"
                         alt="{{ image.alt }}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
            <div ng-repeat="image in images">
                <img ng-src="{{ image.image }}"
                        class="photos"
                        ng-class="{active: mainImageUrl==image.image}">
            </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
```

myApp.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngRoute', 'displayControllers'])
.config(['$routeProvider', 
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'display-images.html',
            controller: 'DisplayImagesCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    }])
.animation('.photos', function() {
    var animateUp = function(element, className, done) {
        if(className != 'active') {
            return;
        }
        element.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 1500,
            display: 'block'
        });

        jQuery(element).animate({
            top: 300
        }, done);

        return function(cancel) {
            if (cancel) {
                element.stop();
            }
        };
    }

    var animateDown = function(element, className, done) {
        if(className != 'active') {
            return;
        }
        element.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 300
        });

        jQuery(element).animate({
            top: -1500
        }, done);

        return function(cancel) {
            if(cancel) {
                element.stop();
            }
        };
    }

    return {
        addClass: animateUp,
        removeClass: animateDown
    };
})
.factory('DisplayImagesService',
    function() {
        return {
            imageObj: function() {
                images = [
                    { image: 'images/animal1.jpg', alt: 'Picture of two sheep'},
                    { image: 'images/animal2.jpg', alt: 'Picture of a dog'},
                    { image: 'images/animal3.jpg', alt: 'Picture of a gorilla'},
                    { image: 'images/animal4.jpg', alt: 'Picture of a bull'},
                    { image: 'images/animal5.jpg', alt: 'Picture of a horse'}
                ];
                return images;
            }
        }
});
```

controller.js

```
var displayControllers = angular.module('displayControllers', []);
displayControllers.controller('DisplayImagesCtrl', ['$scope','DisplayImagesService',
 function($scope, DisplayImagesService) {
    $scope.images = DisplayImagesService.imageObj();

    $scope.setImage = function(imageUrl) {
        $scope.mainImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    $scope.mainImageUrl = 'images/animal1.jpg';
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to fix this problem it seems that in the phonecat tutorial they compensated for it with css in the following way:

They limited the height of the display area.

The set the overflow to hidden.

The background colour of the images is white the same as the background colour of the web page.

I found if I placed my images on a white background using the gimp and limited the height of the display area and set overflow to hidden I could get a result that looks resonable.